# Need help quickly, in printing horizontally

Tags: python, printing, diagram

- I want a diagram too look like this essentially as the output

Comment: you can't generally go back with print(). either you use different functions or you assemble output line by line.

Comment: you actually can use `print("", end="\r", flush=True)` to achieve that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
star_progress = '*'
def progress():
    for p in range(4): # you added one extra
        print(star_progress, end="\t\t\t", sep="")
   
# you cant call any function you write without defining it first  
        
print("Progress",end = '  ')
print("Trailing",end = '  ')
print("Retriever",end = '  ')
print("Excluded")
progress()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `end='  '` in the asterisk printing

```
#Function for Trailing asterisk

star_trailing= '*'
def trailing():
    for p in range(5):
        print(star_trailing, end='  ')

#input
print("progress",end = '  ')
print("Trailing",end = '  ')
print("Retriever",end = '  ')
print("Excluded")
progress()
trailing()
```